# Area of a section bounded by a curve and two tangents

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area, tangent-line

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Calculate the area of a section bounded by a curve $y=x^2+4x+9$ and
>   two tangents in points: $x_1=-3$ and $x_2=0$.

I calculated the equations of the two tangents and I got that $y_1=-2x+0$ and $y_2=4x+9$.

Now I was able to draw the graph. But the question is, how to I calculate the area? I can take the integral

$\int_{-3}^{0} x^2+4x+9$, however, that would be the area of everything under the curve, not just the area of the section bounded by the two tangents.

How do I calculate the area of just the section?

Thanks

Comment: Subtract the areas of the triangles.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How do I get the area of the triangles?

Comment: By integration for instance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two tangent lines meet at $\left(-\frac32,3\right)$. So, in order to determine the area bounded by the graph and the two tangent lines. The tangent line corresponding to $x_1$ is $y=-2x$, whereas the tangent line corresponding to $x_2$ is $y=4x+9$.

[image]

So, all you have to do is to compute$$\int_{-3}^{-3/2}\overbrace{x^2+4x+9-(-2x)}^{\phantom{(x+3)^2}=(x+3)^2}\,\mathrm dx+\int_{-3/2}^0\overbrace{x^2+4x+9-(4x+9)}^{\phantom{x^2}=x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$Each integral is equal to $\frac98$, and therefore your area is equal to $\frac94$.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how did you get the integrals? How did you get $-2x$ and $4x+9$ in the integrals? Thanks

Comment: When $x$ is between $-3$ and $-\frac32$, the graph of $f$ is above the graph of the tangent line passing through $\bigl(-3,f(-3)\bigr)$, which is the line $y=-2x$. So, that part of the area is computed by the integral of $f(x)-(-2x)$ (that is, the function which is above minus the function which is below). A similar argument applies to the second half of your area.

Answer (score 0):

Now, calculate $$2\int\limits_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{0}(x^2+4x+9-(4x+9))dx.$$

Comment: Could you please explain to me why $4x+9$?

Comment: @LukasT Because $y=4x+9$ is a tangent to the parabola $y=x^2+4x+9.$

Answer (score 0):

For calculation of area shift your x axis at y=3 Hence area will be area enclosed between parabola and , x=-3,x=0 and y=3 . From this substract area between tangents and y=3.
Hence Required area is 
$$\int_{-3}^{0} (x^2+4x+6)dx -\frac{27}{4}$$
$$=33-\frac{27}{4}=\frac{105}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There are many ways to find the area $[AED]$ in question,
for example, we can use a bit of geometry:

\begin{align}
[AED]&=[ABCD]-[ABC]-[DEC]
.
\end{align}

The equations of the tangent lines are
\begin{align} 
f_1(x)&=f'(x_1)(x-x_1)+f(x_1)
,\\
f_2(x)&=f'(x_2)(x-x_2)+f(x_2)
.
\end{align}

So, given that

\begin{align} 
f'(x)&=2\,x+4
,
\end{align}

we have

\begin{align} 
f_1(x)&=-2 x
,\\
f_2(x)&=4\,x + 9
,
\end{align}

and we can find the coordinates of the corresponding points 
\begin{align} 
A&=(-3,6)
,\quad
B=(-3,0)
,\quad
C=(0,0)
,\quad
D=(0,9)
,\quad
E=(-\tfrac32,3)
.
\end{align}

Then corresponding areas are

\begin{align} 
[AED]&=
\int_{x_1}^{x2} f(x)\,dx
=
\int_{-3}^{0} x^2+4\,x+9 \,dx
=\left. \tfrac13\,x^3+2\,x^2+9\,x\right|_{x=-3}^{x=0}
=18
,\\
[ABC]&=\tfrac12\,|BC|\cdot|AC|
=\tfrac12\cdot 3\cdot 6
=9
,\\
[DEC]&=
\tfrac12\,|CD|\cdot|E_x|=
\tfrac12\,9\cdot\tfrac32=
\tfrac{27}4
,\\
[AED]&=18-9-\tfrac{27}4
=\tfrac94
.
\end{align}